# how to access json via jquery

Tags: jquery

i have this json in my request

```
    $.get("/shop_possystems/index.php?route=module/cart/ajax_get_individual_prices&current_id=" + current_id + "&standard_id=" + standard + "&professional_id=" + professional + "&premium_id=" + premium + "&quantity=" + quantity,
        function(data) {
            var standard_price     = data.standard_price;
            var professional_price = data.professional_price;
            var premium_price      = data.premium_price;
                        console.log(data);
                    $prettyCheckBox0.text(standard_price);
                    $prettyCheckBox1.text(professional_price);
                    $prettyCheckBox2.text(premium_price);
    });
```

the problem is that the data.standard_price returns undefined but in the console.log i have this

```
 "{"standard_price":"included","professional_price":"add $792.00","premium_price":"add $3372.00"}"
```

whats the deal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to parse the JSON. Put this as the first line of the callback:

```
data = $.parseJSON(data);
```

Alternatively, use `$.getJSON` instead of `$.get` or pass `"json"` as another parameter to `$.get`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use $.parseJSON(string), like this:

```
 $.get("/shop_possystems/index.php?route=module/cart/ajax_get_individual_prices&current_id=" + current_id + "&standard_id=" + standard + "&professional_id=" + professional + "&premium_id=" + premium + "&quantity=" + quantity,
        function(data) {data = $.parseJSON(data);
            var standard_price     = data.standard_price;
            var professional_price = data.professional_price;
            var premium_price      = data.premium_price;
                        console.log(data);
                    $prettyCheckBox0.text(standard_price);
                    $prettyCheckBox1.text(professional_price);
                    $prettyCheckBox2.text(premium_price);
    });
```

Another way is to use $.ajax an specify in `dataType: 'json'` see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

Try using jQuery.getJSON()

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

And when returning your data from the php script, use json_encode()

Answer (score 1):

`console.log` seems to be indicating that you have a string, rather than an actual Javascript object. You need to tell jQuery to treat the content as JSON and to give you the parsed object. The easiest way is to use [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson) instead of [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get):

```
$.getJSON("/shop_possystems/index.php?route=module/cart/ajax_get_individual_prices&current_id=" + current_id + "&standard_id=" + standard + "&professional_id=" + professional + "&premium_id=" + premium + "&quantity=" + quantity,
    function(data) {
        var standard_price     = data.standard_price;
        var professional_price = data.professional_price;
        var premium_price      = data.premium_price;
                    console.log(data);
                $prettyCheckBox0.text(standard_price);
                $prettyCheckBox1.text(professional_price);
                $prettyCheckBox2.text(premium_price);
});
```